# Sudden Instagram API "SCOPE" issue when trying to authorize user and get token - OAuth

Tags: rest, api, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I seem to be getting an error around `scope` when trying to create a token via the Instagram API. This was working perfect until about a week ago. If I remove `scope` then it works, but if I do that I can't access Hashtag searches, so I need that `scope`.

I keep getting the following error:

```
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid scope field(s): public_content"}
```

This is the request URL:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=***CLIENTID***&approval_prompt=force&scope=public_content&response_type=code&redirect_uri=***REDIRECT URL***
```

My app has permissions for public_content as seen here:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Double check the client ID..

Comment: Client ID is good. Maybe `public_content` is deprecated overall.

Comment: @DigitalMC how did you ? with which option you have submitted for approval? instagram not allowing me to submit client for approval for required option selection

Comment: I think we just removed Public Content. Seems we are using the old API and this just isn't supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove "public_content". Only use "basic".